# Porting MySQL Stored Procedure to Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to port a stored procedure from MySQL to Oracle, and I'm having a lot of trouble. I've gone through Oracle documentation, and I'm having trouble doing very basic things like declaring variables properly. I was hoping someone could show me how to properly declare and set variables.

My stored procedure is used to add values to two different tables and ensure that it's being mapped properly and the foreign keys aren't being violated.

Here is my MySQL Code:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=root@% PROCEDURE proc_add_entry(IN theName vARCHAR(50), IN theKey VARCHAR(50), IN theOtherData VARCHAR(50), IN theOtherData2 INT, IN theStartDate DATE, IN theEndDate DaTE, IN theReferenceDate DaTE)
     LANGUAGE SQL
     NOT DETERMINISTIC
     CONTAINS SQL
     SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 BEGIN
 declare theNameID int ;
 declare theKeyID int ;
 declare theOtherDataID int default null;
 declare error bool default false;
 declare continue handler for SQLEXCEPTION
    set error = true;

    set theKeyID = (select KeyID from map_alias ma where ma.alias = trim(theKey));
    set theOtherDataID = (select theOtherDataID from map_otherdata mc where mc.otherdata = trim(theOtherData));

    set theNameID = (select max(nameID) from inserttable);
    set theNameID = theNameID + 1;
    insert into inserttable values (theNameID , theKeyID , theOtherDataID , theOtherData2, theStartDate , 
    theEndDate , theReferenceDate);

    if error = true then
        insert into errors_inserttable values (theNameID , theKeyID , theOtherDataID , theOtherData2, theStartDate , 
    theEndDate , theReferenceDate);
    end if;

    set error = false;
    insert into map_inserttable (theNameID , datasourceid, theName) values (theNameID , 1, theName);
    if error = true then
        insert into errors_map_inserttable  (theNameID , datasourceid, theName) values (theNameID , 1, theName);
    end if;

 END
```

In Oracle, my last statement are being ignored (ORA-00922: Missing or invalid option). It should be a local variable, so I'm not sure why i'm getting that particular error.

I'm struggling to declare the continue handler as well. I'm getting the error:

```
 Error(16,27): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; not null range default character.
```

Here is my oracle code so far:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_ADD_ENTRY
 (
   THENAME IN VARCHAR2  
 , THEKEY IN VARCHAR2  
 , THEOTHERDATA IN VARCHAR2  
 , THEOTHERDATA2 IN NUMBER  
 , THEFIRSTDATE IN DATE  
 , THELASTDATE IN DATE  
 , THEREFERENCEDATE IN DATE  
 ) AS
  THENAMEID INT;
  THEKEYID INT;
  THEOTHERDATAID int;
  ERROR bool default false;
 BEGIN
 declare continue HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION set error = true;



   set THEKEYID = (select KEYID from map_INSERTTABLE mc where mc.Key = trim(THEKEY));
 END PROC_ADD_ENTRY;
```

I'm sure this is stupidly simple for someone that uses oracle, but I'm reading the documentation and I'm seeing conflicting information on where and how to declare variables, continue handlers, and assign values to variables. (is it := or = to assign values? Do i use the word declare after the begin statement to declare variables, or do I do it the way I show below?)

If someone could show me:

a) where to declare a local variable

b) how to assign a value to it (i.e. 1 to an int)

c) how to assign a value from the DB to a variable (set var = select number from table_number tn where tn.number = 1)

d) how to declare a continue handler properly

I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've go the basic structure fine.

```
create or replace procedure <name> (<param list>) as
  <local variables>
begin
  <body>
end <name>;
```

To address your specific questions:

> a) where to declare a local variable

I've marked this section up above.

> b) how to assign a value to it (i.e. 1 to an int)

You would use `:=` for assignment.

eg. `thenameid := 1;`

The data type you want will typically match the sql data types (eg. `NUMBER` for the above) though there are PL/SQL-specific data types such as `PLS_INTEGER`. See the [PL/SQL data types documentation for more details](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm).

> c) how to assign a value from the DB to a variable (set var = select number from table_number tn where tn.number = 1)

You would use the `into` keyword with a locally defined variable to store the value in. eg.

```
l_num_rows number;
select count(*) into l_num_rows from user_objects;
```

> d) how to declare a continue handler properly

If I'm reading understanding your code correctly, you want `set error = true` to be executed every time there is a problem with an sql statement and then you want the stored procedure to carry on.

[Exception handling](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm) is what you are after. You would wrap any or SQL PL/SQL statements that you think may have errors in an exception block like this, with as many exception cases as needed (eg. NO_DATA_FOUND):

```
begin
  <statements that may fail>
exception when <exception name> then
  <action>
...
exception when others then
  <action>
end;
```

"other" is the catchall. You can have just this case handled but as with any error handling it is better practise to catch specific cases first.

---

For completion, here's roughly what your example procedure would look like. I've removed the error code flag as it is not needed and also changed the `int`s to `number`s:

```
create or replace procedure proc_add_entry (
  in thename varchar(50),
  in thekey varchar(50),
  in theotherdata varchar(50),
  in theotherdata2 number,
  in thestartdate date,
  in theenddate date,
  in thereferencedate date
) as
  thenameid number;
  thekeyid number;
  theotherdataid number default null;
begin
  begin
    select keyid into thekeyid from map_alias ma where ma.alias = trim(thekey);

    select theotherdataid into theotherdataid from map_otherdata mc where mc.otherdata = trim(theotherdata);

    select max(nameid) into thenameid from inserttable;
    thenameid := thenameid + 1;

    insert into inserttable values (thenameid, thekeyid, theotherdataid, theotherdata2, thestartdate, theenddate, thereferencedate);
  exception when others then
    insert into errors_inserttable values (thenameid, thekeyid, theotherdataid, theotherdata2, thestartdate, theenddate, thereferencedate);
  end;

  begin
    insert into map_inserttable (thenameid, datasourceid, thename) values (thenameid, 1, thename);
  exception when others then
    insert into errors_map_inserttable (thenameid, datasourceid, thename) values (thenameid, 1, thename);
  end;

end proc_add_entry;
```